# Why wont Mysql field update? - Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to write a function in Java that updates the description and title fields of a Mysql table however when I pass the int variable 'urlid' nothing is added. If I change the urlid variable (at the very end of the query) to another int variable (for example int i = 2) then it works fine. What is it about this urlid that makes things go wrong?

```
public void updateDescription( String desc, String title, int urlid ) throws SQLException, IOException {
        String cutDesc = desc.substring(0, 99);
            Statement stat = connection.createStatement();
            String query = "UPDATE urls SET description = '"+cutDesc+"', title = '"+title+"' WHERE urlid =" + urlid;
            stat.executeUpdate( query );
            stat.close();
    }
```

Comment: What does transaction mean? Sorry I am fairly new to Mysql and I have never heard that term before?

Comment: For the benefit of anyone who might post an answer without knowing all the background - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982527/mysql-statement-in-java-not-executing/22982616#22982616

Comment: paste the stacktrce here

Answer (score 0):

i guess you miss the quotes ,

```
"UPDATE urls SET description = '"+cutDesc+"', title = '"+title+"' WHERE urlid ='"+ urlid+"'";
```

Hope this helps !!

Note: use prepared statements to avoid sql injection . [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Your current quotes do exactly nothing to the java `String` object, I think you forgot to add the single quotes `'` around urlid

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try with `WHERE urlid ='"+ urlid+"'";` at the end.

for your reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: Still nothing is being inserted into the title or description columns

Comment: what values are you passing into the method updateDescription( String desc, String title, int urlid ) ??  if you are passing correct values in correct format it should definitely work. kindly check the values you are providing to the method. you can always use a System.out.println(); to check the values.

Comment: you can also call this method this way updateDescription("abc", "def", 1)